# how to find a route in a graph

Tags: discrete-mathematics, graph-theory

"Dr C is a tourist by nature, and wishes to visit each place once and return to her starting point. Dr D is an explorer, and wishes to traverse every road just once, in either direction; he is prepared to start and finish in different places. Can suitable routes for Drs C and D be found?

The adjaceny list is 
$$
0: 1 3 5 7$$

$$1: 0 2 6 8$$
$$2: 1 3 7$$
$$3: 0 2 4 8$$
$$4: 3 5  $$
$$5: 0 4 6 8$$
$$6: 1 5 7$$
$$7: 0 2 6 8$$
$$8: 1 3 5 7$$

Should i do trial and error method or should i try to sketch the graph (will be easier to find the route but if you can do it by checking the adjacency list then i would want to learn it) ?

Comment: See http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eulerian_path and http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hamiltonian_path

Comment: thanks. i will read it and come back if i still have some problems.

Comment: I know that the routes hare a hamilton cykel and a Eulerian walk, but how can I check if I can get those routes from the adjacency list? Is it enough just by checking the degrees?

Comment: For Dr. D, yes
For Dr. C, there is not "easy" algorithm to decide if such a path exists (you should try to build the path "by hand")

Comment: Could I do like this for Dr. C's route?

I first check if the graph only has one component (one equivalence class, right?). Then I check if the degrees of all vertex v is even. But how can one eulerian walk excist if the all vertex v of the graph does not have an even degree?

Comment: There can't be an Eulerian cycle if some vertex is not of odd degree.  But there can be a trail (a walk).  Check this  : http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eulerian_path - An undirected graph has an Eulerian trail if and only if at most two vertices have odd degre.

Comment: thanks. i just saw that the information the site gave was wrong. they had wrote eulerian walk instead of eulerian cycle. thanks again @manuellafond